# US Entry - B1/2 Visa (Peace of mind)

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, uk-citizens, borders

I'm traveling to the USA in a matter of weeks. I have a B1/2 Tourist Visa (multiple entries 10 Year validity) and am a UK Citizen. I applied for a visa through the UK/US Embassy procedure, as I had a previous arrest for a minor drunk and disorderly offence. The offence did not result in a conviction - The embassy approved my visa. Some say that I could have travelled on ESTA, but the question wording isn't 100% clear, and the official advice is to go via embassy channels.

I've read online that the visa doesn't guarantee entry. I know I've mentioned this before, but does this mean I'm still not guaranteed to get in? I'm really nervous because this holiday means the world to me, I've fully complied with everything.

My crime was not a crime of moral turpitude, and the US Embassy Medical exam proved that I am not an alcohol abuser.

Thanks,

Comment: In  most countries neither an ESTA or a Visa is a garantie for entry. The final decision is always by the immigration officer. Had you only gone with an ESTA, then the officer **may** have had to take your case into consideration. With the issued visa they will assume that the matter has been delt with. Thus the likly hood of getting in is **higher**, but never guaranteed.

Comment: It is unlikely you will have any problems which would be due to this. This matter has been dealt with, your case file has all the evidence in place which supports your case. Although it is not a guarantee, it would be extremely unusual for immigration officer to go against the decision of the consulate post and reverse their decision based on the same evidence. When people are denied entry after visa issuance it usually is due to the new evidence, which the post didn't address or had access to.

Comment: Imagine if you asked the police to guarantee that they would not arrest you the next time you went to Trafalgar Square.  Would they do so?  Of course not. 
 Similarly, you will never get a guarantee of admission.  But the chance of your being refused entry after getting the visa is about as high as that of your being arrested the next time you go to Trafalgar Square.  Stop worrying and enjoy your trip.